# Opening a URL string in new Tab to click the image it loads, unable to read the URL string

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a method where i am opening a URL string in new tab TAB 1, which loads the image and then i am clicking on that image which results in another tab which is my landing URL TAB 2. Now i want to store this landing URL into a string. but it still storing the TAB 1 URL in the string. Following is the method i wrote

```
var selecttxt1 = Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text.GetAttribute("value");
        string getimpression = selecttxt1.Replace("C.ashx", "I.ashx");
        driver.OpenInNewTab(getimpression);
        driver.ClickElement(Click_Impression);
        var aa = driver.Url; 
        Uri uri = new Uri(aa);`enter code here`
        string finallandedurltext = uri.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
        driver.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Window Handle` when you are switch between windows to access the window.

```
var selecttxt1 = Ad_Search_Direct_Link_Text.GetAttribute("value");
        string getimpression = selecttxt1.Replace("C.ashx", "I.ashx");
        driver.OpenInNewTab(getimpression);
        driver.ClickElement(Click_Impression);


        var aa = driver.Url; 
        Uri uri = new Uri(aa);`enter code here`
         string newTabHandle = driver.WindowHandles.Last();
        var newTab = driver.SwitchTo().Window(newTabHandle);
        string finallandedurltext = newTab.GetComponents(UriComponents.Scheme | UriComponents.Host, UriFormat.UriEscaped);
        driver.Close();
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your help kajal but it did not help and throws an exception-
Error CS1061 'IWebDriver' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponents' and no extension method 'GetComponents' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebDriver' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have no idea about c#.however the concept remain same.You have to switch to other window to access the element.just try `newTab.curreturl` if you have such command in c#.however java we have `driver.currenturl`

Comment: you can check how to switch between windows in c#  https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/switch-command-in-selenium-c/

Comment: Thanks for this link. It clarifies where i was wrong. It worked now. I am able to read the new window string